# Android Studio code style for comments

Tags: android, android-studio, coding-style

I'm writing code guidelines for some of our projects on Android. I'd actually like to facilitate this by using Android Studio code style preferences. I'm almost done setting parameters there: *Android Studio->Preferences->Editor->Code Style->Java*.

One thing I'm missing is that we want comments to be formatted like this :

```
// a useful comment
```

Instead of :

```
//a useful comment
```

How do I tell Android Studio to but a space between slashes and the text in the comment? Thanks!

Comment: can you also help me.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71243099/android-studio-code-style-put-a-space-before-comment-text-in-a-multiine-comment

Answer (score 2):

If you press `CTRL /` or `CMD /` it will put `//` at the beginning of the line and the comment will be properly indented.

```
//        comment with two indents
```

For this to work `Comment at first column` must be checked in `Editor->CodeStyle->Java->Wrapping and Braces->Keep when reformatting` like mentioned in another answer.

[image: screenshot]

If you want to write multiline comment you can use `CTRL SHIFT /` or `CMD SHIFT /` That way when you go into new line, you will have one space after the comment start

```
    /*
    * there is space before this*/
```

Comment: Thanks I tried checking: Editor->CodeStyle->Java->Wrapping and Braces->Keep when reformatting but no success. My comments stay as //a useful comment

Comment: try to press enter to go to new line, than press `cmd /` and tell me what happens, where is the caret before and after the press

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved this problem.

I think you can find Code Style -> Java -> Code Generation
There is a `Comment Code` and select the `Add a space at comment start`
I think your problem can be solved.

Comment: Thanks but apparently this is only at code generation (I tried formatting code after setting that). But definitely improves comment guidelines when we generate code :)

Comment: Yes you are right, if you want to format old code, my method doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it under the tab Wrapping and Braces.

Comment: I searched into this section, can you maybe point me at which line it deals with this in "Wrapping and Braces"?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who doesn't know

Under Code Style → Java/Kotlin→Code generation

Uncheck Line comment at first column

Check Add a space at line comment start, then Enforce on reformat

It should be okay

[image]